# Get submenu ul positioned behind a parent div

Tags: html, css, submenu

Trying to figure out if there is any way to get my submenu to appear "behind" one of it's parent divs. The parent div has a background with design elements that I'd like the submenu to appear to be coming out from behind.

Here's the HTML code I'm using:

```
    <div id="header">
    <div id="headerbluebox"><div id="navigationcurves"><div class="page-wrap">
        <h1><a href="softrol/">Softrol</a></h1>
        <div class="menu-main-menu-container">
        <ul id="menu-main-menu" class="menu">
            <li id="menu-item-498" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-498"><a href="#">Solutions</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li><a href="softrol/solutions/softrol-total-plant-solutions/">Softrol Total Plant Management</a></li>
                    <li><a href="softrol/solutions/chemical-systems/">Chemical Systems</a></li>
                    <li><a href="softrol/solutions/rail-systems/">Rail Systems</a></li>
                    <li><a href="softrol/solutions/productivity-solutions/">Productivity Solutions</a></li>
                    <li><a href="softrol/solutions/garment-sort-systems/">Garment Sort Systems</a></li>
                    <li><a href="softrol/solutions/soil-sort-systems/">Soil Sort Systems</a></li>
                    <li><a href="softrol/solutions/management-info-systems/">Management / Info Systems</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-499" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-499"><a href="#">About Us</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li><a href="softrol/about-us/company-history/">Our History</a></li>
                    <li><a href="softrol/about-us/management-bios/">Management Profiles</a></li>
                    <li><a href="softrol/about-us/corporate-brochure/">Corporate Brochure</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-500" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-500"><a href="#">Support</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li><a href="softrol/support/sales-contacts/">Sales Contacts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="softrol/support/service-contacts/">Service Contacts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="softrol/support/faqs/">FAQ&#8217;s</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-501" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-501"><a href="#">News</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li><a href="softrol/category/press-release/">Press Release</a></li>
                    <li><a href="softrol/category/blog/">Blog</a></li>
                    <li><a href="softrol/news/media-resources/">Media Resources</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
        </div>
</div></div></div>
```

And here the CSS

```
    #headerbluebox { background-image:url(images/softrol-header-background.jpg); background-position: center top; background-repeat: no-repeat; overflow: visible; background-color: #002255;  }
#headerbluebox #navigationcurves { background-image: url(images/softrol-menuheader.png); background-position: center top; background-repeat: no-repeat; overflow: visible; height: 175px; position: relative; z-index:600;   }
#header { margin: 0 0 35px 0;  }
#header h1 a { width: 170px; height: 100px; font-size: 0px; display: block; }

/* TOP TIER MENU */
.menu-main-menu-container { padding: 0px; display: block; float: right; margin: -65px 30px 0px 100px; width: 600px; position: relative; height: 65px; margin-bottom: 0px; }
.menu-main-menu-container ul#menu-main-menu { padding: 0px; list-style: none; display: block; float: right; margin: 0px; width: 644px; position: relative; height: 60px; margin-right: -25px;  }
.menu-main-menu-container ul#menu-main-menu li { display: inline-block; }
.menu-main-menu-container ul#menu-main-menu li a { display: inline-block; width: 160px; height: 65px; float: left; font-size: 0px; margin: 0 -3px 0 0; }

/* DROP DOWN MENUS */
ul#menu-main-menu li ul.sub-menu { position: absolute; z-index:-500; display: none; list-style: none; margin-top: 65px; margin-left: -150px; width: 200px; padding-top: 20px; opacity:0.9; background-color: #333; }
ul#menu-main-menu ul.sub-menu li{ float:none; width: 150px; }
ul#menu-main-menu ul.sub-menu li a { display: block; padding: 10px 10px; background-color: #333; border-bottom: 1px solid #333; color: #fff; font-size: 14px; text-transform: uppercase; text-align: center; width: 180px; height: auto; }
ul#menu-main-menu li:hover ul { display: inline-block; }
ul#menu-main-menu li:hover a{ }
ul#menu-main-menu li:hover ul a{ text-decoration:none; }
ul#menu-main-menu li:hover ul li a:hover{ background:#666; color: #fff; opacity: 1; }
/*--- END MENUS ---*/
```

Just need to get the "sub-menu" ul's behind the "navigationcurves" div. Here's a link to see it in action: http://www.brandondhunt.com/softrol

Any help would be greatly appreciated!! Thanks!

Comment: Im afraid not. Due to stacking order, a child cannot appear below a parent.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on my comment...

### Im afraid not

(sorry)

This relates to stacking context/order, in that child elements cannot be stacked beneath their parents, as they are ordered relative to them.

[**More from MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context)

> Within a stacking context, child elements are stacked according to the
>   same rules previously explained. Importantly, the z-index values of
>   its child stacking contexts only have meaning in this parent. Stacking
>   contexts are treated atomically as a single unit in the parent
>   stacking context.

On approach to achieve what you want is to remove the element you wish to place at the back from being a parent, position it as appropriate (`position:`) then give it a lower `z-index` than the element you wish to be in front (or place first in the DOM)

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet would be to bring each list outside of its parent list item so that it is a sibling.

```
<li id="menu-item-498" class="ontop">Solutions</li>
<ul class="sub-menu-498">
  <li><a href="softrol/solutions/chemical-systems/">Chemical Systems</a></li>
  ...
</ul>
```

You can then make sure the list's style is changed even if you hover over the heading using the CSS [adjacent sibling selector](http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/adjacent-sibling-selector-css-selector/):

```
li#menu-item-498:hover + .sub-menu-498,
.sub-menu-498:hover {
  display:inline-block;
  ...

}
```

and ensure the sub menu doesn't show except on hover

```
.sub-menu-498 {
  display:none;
}
```

finally ensure the menu headers appear on top

```
.ontop {
   z-index:999;
}
```

Hope that helps.